# AWS S3: Notification for files in particular folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

in S3 buckets we have a folder where incoming files are being placed. And then some of our system picks it up and processes it.

I want to know how many files in this folder is older than some period and then send a notification to corresponding team.

> I.e. In S3 bucket, if some file arrived today and it's still there even after 3 hours, I want to get notified.

I am thinking to use boto python library to iterate through all the objects inside S3 bucket at schduled interval to check files are folder. And then send notification. However, this pulling solution doesn't seem good.

I am thinking to have some event based solution. I know, S3 has events which I can subscribe using either queue or lambda. However, I don't want to do any action as soon as I have file available, I just want to to check which files are older than some time and send email notification.

can we achieve this using event based solution?

Per hour we are expecting around 1000 files. Once file is processed they are moved to different folder.  However if something goes wrong it will be there.  So in day, I am not expecting more than 10,000 files in one bucket. Consider I have multiple buckets.

Comment: Are the files deleted once they have been processed? How many files arrive each hour? How many are likely to be in the bucket at any one time? (The approach would differ if it is 100 files vs 10,000 files.)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein updated the question.

Comment: You might solve this with three lambdas... one to find objects that need processing and put them in a queue for the second.  The second does the processing (of one file only), and, on success, queues it to the third lambda. The third deletes the named object.  Thus each part of the job is simple, scalable, testable, repeatable, and doesn't timeout.  Bit late now tho.

Answer (score 0):

Itarate through S3 files to do that kind of filter is not a good idea. It can get very slow when you have more than a thousad of files in there. I would suggest you to use a database to store that records.

You can have a dynamodb with 2 columns: file name and upload date. Or, if budget is a problem, you can even have a sqlite3 file on the bucket, and fetch it whenever you need to query or add data to it. I did this using lambda, and it works just fine. Just don't forget to upload the file again when new records are inserted.

Comment: so what you are saying is through AWS lambda put entery in RDS for `file_path, date`. And I could have one more lambda function, Scheduled to iterate through RDS and check if file exists in s3 buckets.

Comment: No. From what I got from you question, you want to trigger the lambda everytime a new file is put on the bucket. Isn't that correct? You can use the same function to add the record, query the older records, and send the notification.

Comment: And again, I don't think you need RDS for this, just a sqlite file stored on the bucket with versioning enabled would do just fine. You fetch the file when the lambda spin and upload it again before exiting. Unles you already have an existing RDS instance and can add a table for this, it would be perfect.

Comment: Nope... I just want notification when some file in bucket is present for let's say more than a day

Comment: So you can just schedule your lambda to run when you want to check the records.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an **Amazon CloudWatch Event rule** that triggers an AWS Lambda function at a desired time interval (eg every 5 minutes or once an hour).

The **AWS Lambda function** could list the desired folder looking for files older than a desired time period. It would be something like this:

```py
import boto3
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

paginator = s3_client.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
page_iterator = paginator.paginate(
    Bucket = 'my-bucket',
    Prefix = 'to-be-processed/'
)

for page in page_iterator:
    for object in page['Contents']:
        if object['LastModified'] < datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc) - timedelta(hours=3):
            // Print name of object older than given age
            print(object['Key'])
```

You could then have it notify somebody. The easiest way would be to send a message to an **Amazon SNS topic**, and then people can **subscribe to that topic via SMS or email** to receive a notification.

The above code is quite simple in that it will find the same file every time, not just the new files that have been added to the notification period.

Comment: I can see `s3api` has `query` option where I can filter based on date. What do you think which option would be faster.  Python SDK for S3API?

Comment: The AWS CLI also uses boto3, so it will not be any faster. Speed is unlikely to be your issue here, so pick whichever one works for you.